# Accessing template helper dictionary in Meteor event handler

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

In Meteor, I'm sending two objects from my db to a template:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  helper1: function() {
    var object1 = this;  // data context set in iron:router...path is context dependent
    // modify some values in object1
    return this;
  },
  helper2: function() {
    return Collection2.find({_id: this.object2_id});
  }
});
```

This template also has an event handler to modify the two objects above. I am trying to access helper1 and helper2 from above, but if I call the data context of the template, I only get access to the unmodified version of object1. How do I access the helpers defined above?

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Access helper2 object and attributes here instead of calling Collection2.find() again
  }
});
```

Comment: There's no way to call helpers with the current public API.

Comment: Peppe, you might know this, but I just found out there is an internal api for accessing helpers - Template.myTemplate.__helpers.get('helper');

Comment: Given this is internal, I assume the api may change in the future, thus it may not be the best idea to use this often in your code.

Comment: Just remember that you can't rely on using `this` in the helpers you call this way, and I guess `Template.instance()` won't work neither, unless you do some more public API violations.

Comment: @bgmaster, `Template.myTemplate.__helpers.get('helper');` is way too hacky, and can get obsolete at any moment in the future. Blaze is not designed to be used this way ... check my answer below

Answer (score 4):

Helpers are just functions and thus can be passed around and assigned to other variables at will, so you could define a function and then assign it the helper2 key of the template helpers and call by it's original reference from the event handler.

```
var helperFunction = function() {
    return Collection2.find({_id: this.object2_id});
};

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    helper1: function() {
        var object1 = this;  // data context set in iron:router...path is context dependent
        // modify some values in object1
        return this;
    },
    helper2: helperFunction
});

Template.myTemplate.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var cursor = helperFunction();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This pattern helps a little with avoiding repeating code, which I was aiming to do. The only thing I would note is this in the function can change. When you call the function in the event handler, this becomes the Window object instead of the data context. I find this odd considering this in the event handler is still the data context. If you can update your answer to reflect this, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: As @bgmaster has noted, you need to call [the call method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and provide the `thisArg` instead of simply calling the function. However, in the event, you don't know what the `thisArg` should be (and it may be different different times `{{helper2}}` has been used, so this doesn't work in general).

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify helpers from events, then, any part of the Meteor application can do, which is against the design philosophy of Blaze!

Blaze is designed to be uni-directional data binding tempting system. What you ask for can be achieved using Angular (used on its own, or side by side with Blaze, look at [THIS](http://angular-meteor.com)), which is by nature a 2-way data binding tempting system.

You may also want to check React, which is also a 2 way data binding