# Meteor currentUser

Tags: javascript, meteor

Using the node.js framework Meteor -

how come the `currentUser` variable is *defined* in a template such as here:

```
<template name="main_template">
  <div class="container">
  {{#if currentUser}}
  {{> add_player_form_template}}
  {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

but when I call `currentUser` from the console, it's *undefined*:

[image]

however, `Meteor.userId` is defined:

[image]

why is this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`{{ currentUser}}` is a helper in the `main_template` template.

In your client Javascript you'll need to define that helper method. Something like:

```
Template.main_template.helpers({
  currentUser: function() {
    return Meteor.userId();
  }
})
```

This may help too http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/templates.

Comment: You'll probably want `return Meteor.user()`

Comment: It's not just a helper in that template, it's a helper in all templates, for free : https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#current-user

Answer (score 9):

[`{{ currentUser }}`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentuser) is a template helper that simply calls `Meteor.user()`.

In the console, you need to call `Meteor.user()`.

Comment: ok, thx, is there any way to access those template helper functions from the console?

Comment: @AlexMills: there's [no public API to call helper functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962532/accessing-template-helper-dictionary-in-meteor-event-handler#comment44318599_27962532) because if you need a helper called from more than one place, you can define it as a function outside the helpers dictionary, and then call it from wherever you want, including passing it as a helper dictionary value. In the particular case of `currentUser`, there is already `Meteor.user()`.